# How do you define the "boundary" of a topological space?

Tags: algebraic-topology, definition

As described [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boundary_%28topology%29) (and as I always thought was the most general definition of boundary), a possible definition of the boundary of a subset $S$ of a topological space $X$ is $\partial S = \overline S \backslash \mathrm{int}(S)$.

I am reading Allen Hatcher's book on algebraic topology, and they often refer to "the" boundary of a topological space, for instance by saying that $\partial D^2 = S^1$. How is this notion of boundary uniquely defined? Because if I take an injection of $D^2$ into $\mathbb R^2$, I'm going to get $S^1$, but if I take the injection of $D^2$ into $\mathbb R^3$, then $D^2$ becomes its own boundary. I know that the $\partial$ is an important operation in topology so I'm trying to figure it out, and I feel like it doesn't quite make sense here.

So can anyone describe precisely what is meant by $\partial X$ when $X$ is a topological space? Or at least explain what is meant by that in particular contexts where it is used.

Comment: This is *not* the topological notion of boundary as you observed. The context you're probably looking for is that of "topological manifolds with boundary".

Comment: @Anthony : I figured it wasn't the definition of the boundary of a topological space... but I guess I'll look up that topological manifold boundary thing!

Comment: As you have observed, $\overline{S}\setminus int(S)$ is not intrinsic to $S$, but also depends on $X$. If you view $D^2$ as a subset of itself, then its boundary becomes empty. Therefore in the context of manifolds a different definition is needed. +1 for a good question.

Comment: For geodesic metric spaces, there is also a notion of boundary obtained by considering equivalence classes of geodesic rays 'tending to infinity'.

Comment: @Jyrki : Yes, that is precisely my remark...

Comment: @Jyrki: the two definitions agree if you consider $D^2$ to be a subset of $\mathbb R^2$.

Comment: @RyanBudney : Sure, but if we are to use $\partial$ on some family of spaces, we want an *intrinsic* notion of boundary, not something that requires an embedding into $\mathbb R^2$ like you mentioned, which is the point of my question, and the answer given by E.O answers that.

Comment: A more general definition would be to talk about the local homeomorphism type at a point in a topological space.  For a manifold with boundary there are only two such points, interior points and boundary points.  This has the advantage of making sense in arbitrary topological spaces.

Comment: @Ryan : Are you just making guesses as to what the definition should be? Because what I'm asking about is that some books already *have* a definition but I don't find it in the books, i.e. they use the $\partial$ everywhere to denote boundary. I am not asking for suggestions of a definition, some definition already exists and I want to know what it is. I believe E.O. gave what I was looking for.

Comment: I don't understand where you're coming from.  Words like "should" are loaded words.  You haven't given context for what you intend by this.  Definitions are functional.  I've just given you a more functional definition to work with, if you so choose.

Comment: Generally speaking if $X$ is only a topological space, there is no definition for the term "boundary".  But what I'm given you above is about as close as it can get.  Hatcher isn't using anything that general.  Hatcher is thinking in the context of my first comment -- everything is in Euclidean space so you don't need general definitions.  Just stick with Euclidean-space notions and that suffices.

Comment: Um... no need to insult my English, and I used the word should because I believe you were trying to define a notion of boundary for spaces in which there is not already a "generally accepted definition". Sorry if I sounded rude. I think my question was pretty clear in the sense that I was looking for Allen Hatcher's definition because I couldn't find it anywhere. But these are interesting comments that you just made.

Comment: Oh, Hatcher is using the convention in my first comment.  He does not assume people are familiar with "manifolds with boundary".

Comment: Small point but I wasn't addressing your English and there was no implied insult on my part.

Comment: Good to know :D cheers

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The notion of boundary that you are looking for comes from the definition of topological manifolds with boundary. As opposed to a regular manifold $X$, a manifold with boundary has the property that each point in $X$ has an open neighborhood which is homeomorphic to an open set in the euclidean half space $\mathbb{R}_+^n=\{(x_1,\dots,x_n)\in\mathbb{R^n}:x_n\ge0\}$. Thus we then define $\partial X$ to be the points which when mapped to $\mathbb{R}_+^n$ have $x_n=0$.

This definition has the benefit that an embedding of $X$ into some other space does not change $\partial X$. Thus $\partial D^2=S^1$ irregardless of whether you view it as living in $\mathbb{R}^2$ or in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: When you say "all points in $X$", you mean "each point of $X$ has some neighborhood such that"?

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva thanks! I have fixed the error now

Comment: This seems to restrict to a very particular kind of space, i.e. those whose boundary is $(n-1)$-dimensional (i.e. in the sense that its boundary has the property that each point has an open neighborhood that maps homeomorphically to an open set in $\mathbb R^{n-1}_+$. I would think, for instance, that in this "manifold with boundary" context, if you see the letter $P$ as a topological space (where the hole in the $P$ is considered as its interior, i.e. $\pi_1(P) = 0$), then the tail of the $P$ would be a part of its boundary, which does not seem the case with your definition.

Comment: I'm asking because I see this chapter with cell-complexes in my book where they glue a bunch of stuff together and its possible to glue a line to a disk (to get the letter $P$ for instance). How does one go around that in the literature? Or is it even a problem?

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva you correct in that the boundary is necessarily $(n-1)$-dimensional. For your example though, $P$ is not a manifold. When you map the tail to $\mathbb{R}^2$, it will be a line. But lines are not open in $\mathbb{R}^2$ so $P$ is not a manifold.

Comment: While the definition I give is independent of the embedding of the space, it has the drawback that it does not always coincide with the definition for the boundary of a topological space. [This](http://wolfweb.unr.edu/homepage/jabuka/Classes/2006_spring/topology/Notes/09%20-%20Manifolds%20with%20boundary.pdf) might be helpful.

Comment: Oh so for cell-complexes the thing has to be a manifold, so the attaching of $D^n$'s to the $n$-skeleton cannot be done in the way such as the letter $P$ I described. Interesting.

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva, cell-complexes are more general than manifolds. My point was that if you want to apply the above definition, the cell-complex has to be a manifold as well. In general, when working with complexes it makes more sense to distinguish between different dimensional boundaries and so you more typically refer to some k-dimensional boundary rather than the boundary of the whole thing. This is dealt rigorously in the section on simplical and singular homology.

Comment: I wonder if the following definition may be applied to more general classes of topological spaces. Define $\partial X$ as the largest set, the exclusion of which does not change any of the homotopy classes $S^n\rightarrow X$. Is this a viable definition?
For example, if $X=(0,1]$, then 1 is the only point whose exclusion does not disturb the connectedness.

Answer (score 4):

The concept of boundary can be extended to the (regular) [CW-complexes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CW_complex), as suggested [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/480314/homotopy-problem-for-infinite-dimensional-topological-space-iv).

The boundary of a (regular) CW-complex $X$ is :  $$\partial X := \overline{\bigcup_{n \ge 0}(\bigcup_{c \in \text{n-cells}} \partial c) / (\bigcup_{c \ne c'\in \text{n-cells}} (\partial c \cap \partial c'))}$$

**Definition** : The notation "$n$-cells" above, is the set of closed $n$-cells.

---

**Example** : Let $X$ be a topological space with the following simplicial complex structure :
[image]

**All the sets** :

- $0$-cells $=\{ A,B,C,D,E,F \}$
- $1$-cells $=\{ [A,B],[B,C],[C,D], [D,E],[E,A],[A,F]...  \}$
- $2$-cells $=\{ [A,B,F],[B,C,F],[C,D,F], [D,E,F],[E,A,F]\}$

**Now** :

- $\partial A = \partial B = ... = \partial F = \emptyset$
- $\partial [A,B] = \{A,B \}$ , $\partial [B,C] = \{B,C \}$ , ....
- $\partial [A,B,F] = [A,B] \cup [B,F] \cup [A,F] $, $\partial [B,C,F] = [B,C] \cup [C,F] \cup [B,F] $, ...

**So** :

- $(\bigcup_{c \in \text{0-cells}} \partial c) / (\bigcup_{c \ne c'\in \text{0-cells}} (\partial c \cap \partial c')) = \emptyset$
- $(\bigcup_{c \in \text{1-cells}} \partial c) / (\bigcup_{c \ne c'\in \text{1-cells}} (\partial c \cap \partial c')) = \emptyset$
- $(\bigcup_{c \in \text{2-cells}} \partial c) / (\bigcup_{c \ne c'\in \text{2-cells}} (\partial c \cap \partial c')) = (A,B) \cup (B,C) \cup (C,D) \cup (D,E) \cup (E,A)$

**Conclusion** : $\partial X = [A,B] \cup [B,C] \cup [C,D] \cup [D,E] \cup [E,A]$

---

**Questions** : Let $X$ be a topological space admitting a (regular) CW-complex structure :

- Does $\partial X$ depend on the choice (regular) CW-complex structure ?
- Can we extend this definition for all the topological spaces ?

Comment: Yeah... I actually hate CW complexes ; in Hatcher's book I feel like it is the most handwavy explanation I ever read. Maybe I am just not a CW complex kind of guy, but this thing is seriously vague to me. I don't understand most of it, nor do I understand your answer... sorry. (It's not your fault.)

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva : perhaps a good way to understand what does it mean, is by taking an example : look at various simplicial complexes structure (instead of CW complex)  on a disk, and see that we obtain  its boundary by this process. I hope I have helped you, else, never mind !

Comment: Yeah no, didn't help. I think I just need to find various points of view until one of them rings a bell and then I'll figure it out. But thanks for trying, I appreciate it.

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva : I have edited an explicit example. Maybe it's more understandable now.

Comment: So if I understand well, you take the union over all the boundaries of your $n$-disks for $X^n$, but you remove the boundaries that two $n$-disks can share. Hm. It is not clear to me that this definition does not depend on the chosen CW-complex structure, but it seems obvious (i.e. I can see it but I don't see how to prove it).

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva : I warn you that if the local dimension of the space is constant, then we can probably only deal with n-cells (with n the global dimension), as you write and as my example; but if the local dimension is not constant then we need to deal with r-cells with r≤n. I don't know if this definition depends on the choice, that why I ask, but I guess **no** (with an easy proof).

Comment: Hey @SébastienPalcoux, you already know that the notion of boundary for not regular CW-structures depends on CW-structure - do you remember my example with the sphere?

Comment: You have a mistake in your calculation. The boundary should be: $\partial X = (A,B) \cup (B,C) \cup (C,D) \cup (D,E) \cup (E,A)$ (without the vertices!). Thus it easily follows that the boundary highly depends on (even regular) CW-structure.

Comment: @savick01 : You're right about the mistake, but in my opinion, we just need to improve a little the formula for $\partial$, for example by taking the topological completion.

Comment: @savick01 : That's it. If it's not enough, I think we can improve it, so that it doesn't depend on the choice of the CW-complex structure (even non-regular). So the questions are still open.

Comment: @SébastienPalcoux If you want to work with non-regular CW-structures, you should improve the definition so that it handles well at least the examples which I just recalled.

Comment: @savick01 : but this formula works for the sphere with one 0-cell and one 2-cell, just try.

Comment: I expect any legitimate definition of a boundary to be closed, since you want $X$ to be the disjoint union of its interior and its boundary, and the interior should be open...  :)

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva : I'm not sure to understand the goal of your comment, could you please reformulate it?

Comment: @Sébastien : I think some comments were deleted or edited, but I have a vague souvenir of seeing $\partial X = (A,B) \cup \dots$ and the fact that this $\partial X$ was open was a bit weird, and the comment was about the modification where you took the closure of your expression instead of its original form. Something like that.